# Create Umbrella framework using Carthage or CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, carthage, swift-framework

I have created Umbrella framework by adding sub-framework manually.

I wanted to know how to manage dependency of this sub-frameworks using   Carthage or Cocoapods.

I know that creating Umbrella framework is highly discouraged by Apple.

I also wanted to make that third party framework installation optional for the application developer to know him all the dependencies inside the framework and make the framework size minimum.

Please suggest me what will be the best way to manage sub-framework dependencies (Carthage or Cocoapods)?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: According to https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/135 **carthage update --use-submodules**

Comment: @StephenChen what will be the best way to manage dependencies?

Comment: For me I like carthage more than cocoapods. You can think git vs svn. decentralization vs centralization. For you case I don't know what is better way to manager your's. Can you provide more detail what kind of the code you want to write into your framework or sub-frameworks

Comment: The code in the framework will be of the network, UI type. Please provide any documentation for Carthage to handle submodules dependencies.

Comment: Search **Using submodules for dependencies** inside https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage, maybe could be help

Comment: Sure I will check that, do you have any idea of making sub-frameworks installation optional for Application Developer? I want app developer to install that submodules dependencies into my framework.

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/Moya/Moya. search for **NOTE: At this time**, they build all dependencies first but let developer delete the unused frameworks themself. Maybe you can write a script with arguments to control optional or required sub-frameworks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167859/discussion-between-stephen-chen-and-jarvis-the-avenger).